# Implement dynamic xpath in XSLT: for-each-group

Tags: xslt, xpath, foreach, group-by, saxon

I am trying to use saxon:evaluate to reduce repeated code in an xsl function.
However anything I try returns an error.

This is a section of the repetitive code.

```
<!--Select by outputclass and group by attribute-->
<xsl:when test="$from='oclass-attribute'">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$compose//*[contains(@outputclass,$sel)]" group-by="@*[name()=$group]">
        <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()" />
        <element key="{current-grouping-key()}">
            <xsl:if test="number(current-group()[1])=number(current-group()[1])">
                <xsl:attribute name="max" select="max(current-group())"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="sum" select="sum(current-group())"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[1]"/>
        </element>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:when>

<!--Select by node and group by child node-->
<xsl:when test="$from='node-childnode'">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$compose//*[name()=$sel]" group-by="child::*[name()=$group]">
        <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()" />
        <element key="{current-grouping-key()}">
            <xsl:if test="number(current-group()[1])=number(current-group()[1])">
                <xsl:attribute name="max" select="max(current-group())"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="sum" select="sum(current-group())"/>
            </xsl:if> 
            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[1]"/>
        </element>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:when>
```

What I want is to pass a parameter dictating whether it is an element-name or outputclass-attribute that is selected.

Then another parameter dictating what to group by: attribute or parent, child, following or preceding node.

What I have tried is below:

```
<xsl:variable name="oSel">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="starts-with($from,'oclass-')">
                <xsl:value-of select="$compose//*[contains(@outputclass,$sel)]"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="starts-with($from,'node-')">
                <xsl:value-of select="$compose//*[name()=$sel]"/>    
            </xsl:when> 
            <xsl:otherwise/>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="oGroup">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="ends-with($from,'-attribute')">
                <xsl:value-of select="*/@*[local-name()=$group]"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="ends-with($from,'-childnode')">
                <xsl:value-of select="*/*[name()=$group]"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="ends-with($from,'-parentnode')">
                <xsl:value-of select="parent::*[name()=$group]"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="ends-with($from,'-followingnode')">
                <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*[name()=$group][1]"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="ends-with($from,'-precedingnode')">
                <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::*[name()=$group][1]"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise/>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="test">
        <!--<xsl:for-each-group select="saxon:evaluate($oSel)" group-by="saxon:evaluate($oGroup)">-->
            <xsl:for-each-group select="saxon:evaluate($oSel)" group-by="saxon:evaluate($oGroup)">
            <element key="{current-grouping-key()}">
                <xsl:if test="number(current-group()[1])=number(current-group()[1])">
                    <xsl:attribute name="max" select="max(current-group())"/>
                    <xsl:attribute name="sum" select="sum(current-group())"/>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[1]"/>
            </element>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:variable>
```

I have looked into the saxon documentation and tried all sorts of solutions but none of them are working. Is it possible to do this?

Should have added that I am using Saxon 9.1.0.8 - Sorry, still new to XSLT

Comment: Please state which Saxon version and edition exactly you use.

Comment: Also note that XPath has an `if else` expression that you could use directly in the `select` and/or `group-by` expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `saxon:evaluate()` isn't the right tool for the job.

Now, why isn't it working? To declare the value of $oSel, you've done something like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$compose//*[contains(@outputclass,$sel)]"/>
```

which evaluates the expression in the select attribute and returns its result. But you're then passing $oSel to `saxon:evaluate()`, which expects a string containing an XPath expression. I think you're trying to bind the variable to the expression "$compose//*[contains(@outputclass,$sel)]", not to the result of evaluating this expression. To do that you would have to write

```
   <xsl:value-of select="'$compose//*[contains(@outputclass,$sel)]'"/>
```

Note the extra quotes; but that would now fail because the expression passed to `saxon:evaluate()` can't explicitly use variables such as `$compose` (there's a mechanism to pass parameters, but you don't really want to go there).

In XSLT 3.0 `saxon:evaluate` is superseded by the standard instruction `xsl:evaluate`; but you don't want that one either.

The right mechanism to be using here is *higher order functions*.

In XSLT 3.0 you can write

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="$compose//*[$predicate(.)]" group-by="$grouping-key(.)">
```

Where `$predicate` and `$grouping-key` are variables bound to user-defined functions. You can bind these variables with logic like this:

```
 <xsl:variable name="predicate" as="function(element()) as xs:boolean">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="starts-with($from,'oclass-')">
            <xsl:sequence select="function($n){contains($n/@outputclass,$sel)}"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="starts-with($from,'node-')">
            <xsl:sequence select="function($n){name($n)=$sel}"/>    
        </xsl:when> 
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27786927/replacing-xpath-expression-with-variable-function/27789366#27789366

Comment: Thanks for your help Michael, unfortunately I am currently using an old version of Saxon that does not support XSLT 3.0. 

I should have stated that I was using version 9.1 - sorry still very new to using Saxon and XSLT. I've chased up my company to see if they can provide a newer version.

Comment: It's always nice to have the opportunity to show how the newer features of the language can deliver a real benefit!

Answer (score 1):

Change the xpath as below.

```
$compose//*[name()=$sel or contains(@outputclass,$sel)]
```

Here is the final code looks like

```
<xsl:when test="$from='oclass-attribute'">
<xsl:for-each-group select="$compose//*[name()=$sel or contains(@outputclass,$sel)]" group-by="@*[name()=$group]">
    <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()" />
    <element key="{current-grouping-key()}">
        <xsl:if test="number(current-group()[1])=number(current-group()[1])">
            <xsl:attribute name="max" select="max(current-group())"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="sum" select="sum(current-group())"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[1]"/>
    </element>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
select="if ($from='oclass-attribute') then $compose//*[contains(@outputclass,$sel)] else $compose//*[name()=$sel]"
```

and use the same approach for the `group-by` attribute:

```
group-by="if ($from='oclass-attribute') then @*[name()=$group] else child::*[name()=$group]"
```

Comment: Thanks martin. I will try to use this with 'else-if' as you have suggested. I have also tried Micheal's solution but unless my company will provide me with a newer version of Saxon it will not work - I'm currently using 9.1.

Comment: The open-source Saxon HE edition is available  in the latest releases 9.8 or 9.9 to support XSLT 3. HE however does not support higher-order functions though you could at least use `xsl:function` to write predicate or group-by functions in a bit more structured and maintainable way than using `if .. else`. But try whether it works, at least for the first two samples you have shown it should do and for the longer I only think stuffing all into lots of `if () then else if () then else if ()` becomes unreadable but should work at least as well.